# Is it Possible to get the base 64 of graph without showing it on page / canvas (Graph.Js)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails, chart.js

I need to get the base-64 only of the data set i give and save it as image. The issue i am facing is that i'm unable to get the base-64 only. First I need to draw the canvas then i'm getting the base-64 of that. Is it possible that without displaying the graph on the html page I get base-64 of it? Please advice

Answer (score 0):

You can try with red-agate-svg-canvas package, it allows you to render the charts on the server-side, but should work on modern web browsers too.

[Code here](https://github.com/shellyln/chart.js-node-ssr-example/blob/master/src/index.ts)

Hope that helps.